# Python for loop append pandas dataframe - how to save progress?

Tags: python, pandas, openai-api

I'm trying to send multiple requests from a dataframe to chatGPT and append results into a new column. However, my for loop would break if there is a network issue (like overcrowding or server down).

I would lose all processed data in this code. I need to improve this:

1. Do you know how can I output the results for everytime when there is a completed
   request? so that I can still retrieve the completed data
2. How can I ignore error message and continue iteration?

Thanks!

```
results = []

for line in df2500['phrase']:
  results.append(openai.ChatCompletion.create(
      model="gpt-3.5-turbo",
      temperature=0.3,
      messages=[{"role": "system", "content": line }],
      max_tokens=2500), ignore_index=True)
  time.sleep(5)

df2500['summarized'] = results
  # df2500['summarized'] = pd.concat(results, ignore_index=True)
df2500.to_csv('chatGPT-SG-part1-2500.csv', index=False)
  # results.append(completion([line]))
```

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/ "Stack Overflow")! Open ended and opinion based questions that boil down to subjective responses are generally not a good fit for this site, since there generally is not a single correct answer but a range of opinions based on different approaches. Give a good read over [Where to Start](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6366/where-to-start/6367#6367), and  [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example "Minimal Reproducible Example") then edit your post.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, my suggested solution is not the only one, and there probably are better ones. But here it goes:

A simple approach may be to save after a few iterations,
This way, you could continue requesting whenever you find it failed (From the last point- you could run on i in range(len(df2500['phrase'])) and set line = df2500['phrase'][i].
Just rerun the chunk of code.

```
import pandas as pd

try:
    results = pd.read_csv('chatGPT-SG-part1-2500.csv')['summarized']
except:
    results = []

for i in range(len(results), len(df2500['phrase'])):
    line = df2500['phrase'][i]
    cur_res = openai.ChatCompletion.create(
        model="gpt-3.5-turbo",
        temperature=0.3,
        messages=[{"role": "system", "content": line }],
        max_tokens=2500)
    
    results.append(cur_res, ignore_index=True)
    df2500['summarized'] = results
    df2500.to_csv('chatGPT-SG-part1-2500.csv', index=False)

    time.sleep(5)

df2500['summarized'] = results
df2500.to_csv('chatGPT-SG-part1-2500.csv', index=False)
```